# Can anyone recommend a good/safe free spectrum visualizer?

Tags: video-editor, audio, visual-effects

Something that can generate fairly nice displays for videos would be good. Can just be the generic type where it displays differing frequencies as bars, but something nicer than the harsh ffmpeg generated ones for example.

Wondering if there's something via a player like vlc I can use, i tried their built-in ones though alrdy and they were bad.

State if you do not have personal experience with the programs suggested.

Comment: This question might be suited for Software Recommendation SE but is unfortunately not on topic here for being a recommendation question and also not really production related.

Comment: So this forum is only for exporting your video then? I guess the lack of editing in the title would foreshadow that. When I hear video production I assumed every step in creating a video would be covered here. But this wasn't getting an answer anyways, so whatever.

Comment: If your question is about creating an audio spectrum animation for a video that is absolutely on topic here!
The way you worded your question it sounds like you are searching for a software that generates a live spectrum for you.
Which is debatable if its production related, most people asking for these kind of things are looking for a cool visualizer for their party.

If your purpose is to analyse your audio spectrum during recording that is f.e. absolutely on topic. In that case word your question as a "how to?" rather than "whats the best?" or "what is a good (...)?".

Comment: Well you seem to know that's exactly what I am seeking. its not worth debating tho. but for ex) if i ask 'how to'...it changes nothing. i can make one in ffmpeg eez and its bad quality but it answers the how to. im looking for subjective quality by default and that's the problem, if you want you can try to edit my question to fit ur standards...but that's subjective standards as well. theres no way to make my query fit the rules of the exchange without someone being able to take issue with it. But do what you want, i dont care...no answers anyways.

Comment: I get the frustration with that rule. I'm not their biggest fan either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use elgato its pretty good
they make the stream deck

Comment: That actually worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

[Foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/)
Is what I use for visualizations.